# Dynamically moving a fixed position button?

Tags: html, css, angular, css-transitions, css-transforms

Trying to figure out the semantics behind why this works.

In this admin dashboard there's a settings button that is fixed to the right side of the UI.

https://www.akveo.com/ngx-admin/pages/layout/stepper

If we click the settings button the settings panel expands and this moves the button.

However if we look at the `right` css position (With the developer tools) it is still set to `0` after the button is moved.

Just curious how this works?  My understanding is the `fixed` positioning works relative to the viewport, so I was expecting the button to stay in place and the panel to cover it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the button is clicked, a class called 'expanded' gets added to the 'ngx-toggle-settings-button element'

this 'expanded' class contains the rule 'transform: translateX(-16rem);' which moves the element and the button inside 16rem units in the negative x-axis

Comment: OH ... AWESOME!!  I get it now.  It translates `-16rem` when the `expanded` class is added ... but the `right` position stays at 0 anyways ... SWEET - THANKS!!  And Welcome to SO!!